# statsmodels ARIMA predict is giving me predictions of the differenced signal instead of predictions of the actual signal. What mistake am I making?

Tags: statsmodels, predict, arima

The signal looks as such

[original signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgEiW.png)

The differenced signal obtained by using *plot(output.diff())* looks as such

[differenced signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e8Xr.png)

Next the parameters of the ARIMA model were obtained by analyzing the ACF and PACF

The model was fit in the following manner

*model = ARIMA(output.values, order=(2,1,1))*

*model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)*

When I used

*model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)*

*plt.show()*

It is perfect!

[result using plot_predict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Ko8.png)

but when i use *plt.plot(model_fit.predict(dynamic=False))*

It gives a predictions of the differenced signal

[result using predict of arima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niMeT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the model `sm.tsa.ARIMA`, then you can use the following:

```
plt.plot(model_fit.predict(dynamic=False, typ='levels'))
```

However, this model is deprecated and will be removed in future Statsmodels versions. For compatibility with future versions, you can use the new ARIMA model:

`from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA`

or

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(output.values, order=(2,1,1))
```

This newer model will automatically produce forecasts and predictions of the actual signal, so you do not need to use `typ='levels'` in this case.